# How to serve static files like javascript css images and pdfs in production environment django+static+nginx

Tags: nginx, static, production-environment, django-2.2

1.My environment is Redhat 7, Django 2.2, nginx version: nginx/1.15.12.
I have two static locations and I need to be served at both times. The first location in on the same server and second location is a mounted network drive where store images and all other pdfs.

There are two problems.
1. How to serve both static locations.
The two locations are 
a)/www/AutomationServices/static
b)/storage/Investigator_Validator. 
In nginx conf i tried

```
 location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /www/AutomationServices/static;
       try_files $uri $uri/  @secondStatic;
    }
    location /storage/ {
        root /storage/Investigator_Validator;
    }
    location @secondStatic{
        root /storage/Investigator_Validator;
        }
```

I have multiple folders under /storage/Investigator_Validator. In each subfolder there are pdfs,images and text files grouped according to their classification. When I tried to serve them its not working. But When I tried python manage.py collectstatic the folders and files in the /storage/Investigator_Validator are copied to this folder /www/AutomationServices/static. It worked that time but the files in /storage/Investigator_Validator changes dynamically so its not good to run python manage.py collectstatic everytime when i create those images.

Need to serve two static locations using nginx webserver. How to search subfolders in folders for js,css,images files using nginx.

Answer (score 1):

So the URI `/static/foo/bar.css` may be found in `/www/AutomationServices/static/foo/bar.css` or `/storage/Investigator_Validator/foo/bar.css`. The latter not including `/static/` as part of the pathname.

There are a number of ways to achieve this, one being to use a *regular expression* `location` to capture the tail end of the URI. The `root` is set to a common root directory (in this case `/`) and `try_files` is used to test each path in turn.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/static/(.*)$ {
    root /;
    try_files /www/AutomationServices/static/$1 /storage/Investigator_Validator/$1 =404;
}
```

Comment: Should I remove this code location ```/static/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /www/AutomationServices/static;
       try_files $uri $uri/  @secondStatic;
    }
    location /storage/ {
        root /storage/Investigator_Validator;
    }
    location @secondStatic{
        root /storage/Investigator_Validator;
        }```

Comment: ```Not Found: /static/GS-US-419-4015/volfova-miroslava-20171206-419-4015-1572.png
[pid: 15750|app: 0|req: 4/7] 10.20.89.127 () {46 vars in 960 bytes} [Mon Jul 15 20:05:56 2019] GET /static/GS-US-419-4015/volfova-miroslava-20171206-419-4015-1572.png => generated 1933 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 5 headers in 168 bytes (1 switches on core 0)``` Still not found. I removed all static location and just put the suggestion you gave but js and css are working from 1st location but not from second location.

Comment: What is the pathname for that file?

Comment: Actual path for that file is ```/storage/Investigator_Validator/GS-US-419-4015/volfova-miroslava-20171206-419-4015-1572.png``` and static should get ```/static/GS-US-419-4015/volfova-miroslava-20171206-419-4015-1572.png```